# Why does the axle need to be rotated in a turbine generator?

Tags: forces, magnetic-fields, electrons, electric-current, conductors

Inside a turbine a wire rotates between the poles of a magnet, i.e. rotating inside the magnetic field, so that the field forces the electrons in the wire to move and generate current. But why does the conductor wire need to rotate between the two poles of the magnet? Why can't it generate current when the wire is stationary?

Comment: Please have a look at [Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction) of electromagnetic induction !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having some misconceptions

1. Wire(more pricisely axle) is not rotated between magnetic field in a turbine generator.Wire(more pricisely axle) is used to rotate an coil (present between magnetic fields) present in generator.
2. Magnetic field itself can not force electrons in a conductor to move untill it is at rest.
3. We need an moving conductor so that a force can be applied on electrons by magnetic field. (F=qv*B here q is charge on electron, v is velocity of conductor and B is magnetic field)
4. A turbine and generator are two different things.
5. Turbine just rotates that wire but to produce electric current you have to connect the ends of that wire ( better to say it axle not wire )to an generator.
6. A generator converts that rotating mechanical energy into electrical energy
7. A generator have magnets not the turbine.

   8.Axle ( you like the word wire) does not contain current.

Now why do you need to rotate that turbine is because generator requires mechanical energy

How does it do it ?

As follows

According to faraday's law of electromagnetic induction current will be induced in the circuit (coil) if magnetic flux through the circuit(coil) changes with time .
     If you do not rotate the turbine then there will be no flux change and hence no emf or current induced.

Remember you can also change the flux by

1.Keeping the circuit stationary and moving the magnets 
2. Changing the shape of coil (circuit) so that area changes
3.changing magnitude of magnetic field
4.many more

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer. But what if i increase the strength of the magnetic field? Will it generate current even if both the axle and magnet are at rest? And by the way why is it necessary to change the flux (what flux is it, magnetic flux or electron flux) ? Also what is a flux, is it flowing?

Comment: Also instead of a magnetic field can i use a electric field?

Comment: I am talking about Magnetic flux here.Flux is not flowing,it is what amount is flowing through a plane at a particular orientation.Here magnetic field lines are flowing. Yes increase or decrease in magnetic field strength can lead to current induction as flux changes or the magnetic field lines flowing through coil will change. Yes current can be induced if both axle and magnet are at rest because we can change flux by changing magnetic strength and even shrinking or expanding the coil

Comment: Why to change flux ?                    Electric field and Magnetic field are related and we study them in Electromagnetism.They can be interconverted. Changing magnetic field with time produces electric field in the circuit and that makes the current flow.           And if we use electric field than changing electric field might produce magnetic field which is of no use in circuit as it can not do work or make electrons move. Electric field can do work but magnetic field can not.